# Questions are clipped

Tags: bug, status-completed

In addition to the *highly* irritating "show more" prompt (can I disable it?), I noticed SO today clipping text on the right side of the questions, both in Firefox and Chrome. Let me know if you need screen shots.

Chrome was similar, clips in different places, and had "Show More" after the last line where it was unnecessary.

I can see by the downvotes that bug reports are not welcome here.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots, specific versions of Chrome and Firefox, and screen resolution would definitely help.

Comment: I'm not seeing this on Chrome version 41. I haven't noticed any changes today.

Comment: The clip on the right is a bug (digging), the clip on the bottom (removed with the "show more") is [meta-tag:status-bydesign].  The latter is only applied to relatively tall questions, and only on that page (which is odd for containing multiple questions in full).

Answer (score 1):

[Per my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290920/questions-are-clipped#comment179941_290920), the "show more" is by design on that page due it listing multiple questions*.

However the right side clipping was a bug, and has been fixed in the latest build.

<sub>*That whole thing (the page, the inline answering, and the links into it) is experimental at the moment, it won't be clear whether any of it sticks around for a little bit.</sub>